# In file csv to import in table mysql, for new line, is better use \n , \r or \r\n?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, notepad++, newline

I want to create a `CSV File` to import in a `MySql` table , but i don't know which is the better new line in my editor (Notepad++).

Should I create a new line in editor with:

**A**

```
\n
```

---

**B**

```
\r
```

---

**C**

```
\r\n
```

---

And also explain why?
Thanks a lot and sorry for my english...

Comment: why not try it and see? And not sure why the SQL database is relevant to this, if it's just about choosing the best newline. Also not that different O/Ss often use different line endings by default.

Comment: @ADyson because i dont'have now a database and i'm learning

Comment: yes, but how you store the data (DB, or file) is not relevant to which line ending you choose to use. You can store either one in the database, or in a file. The database does not affect it, and also is not affected by it.

Comment: Hoping i'll translate well what you write, in theory i could separate csv'lines by ";" and then when import file say that line terminied by ";". Right ?

Comment: I think I have misunderstood the question. I thought you were asking about what characters to use in order to enable _re-display_ of the text in Notepad++. What you actually want to know is what character to use when creating the CSV, so that MySQL will know it's a new line? Well, if you are typing this by hand, just press the Enter key and Notepad++ will do the rest...

Comment: and if i create new line with <br> tag (by javascript code) ? for notepad++, new line created with js code with <br>, is also \n or \r\n. What do you think ? is same thing ?

Comment: no, <br> is only understood by a browser, not by a text editor such as Notepad++.

Comment: no you don't understand cause my bad english... i mean that new line is created (with my javascript code) with tag <br> than copy and paste result in notepad++ and for it between each new line there's \n

Answer (score 2):

It is a `CSV` file. So fields terminated by `,` and lines terminated by `\n`.
 And you can use below:

```
load data local infile 'filename.csv' into table tablename fields terminated by ','
  enclosed by '"'
  lines terminated by '\n'
    (column_names)
```

Comment: i know that is csv file but i would to know the better way if import it in table mysql

Comment: and why terminied by \n and not \r or \r\n ? what is difference ?

Comment: \r = CR (Carriage Return) ---use mostly for Mac OS

\n = LF (Line Feed)-- Used as a new line character in Unix

\r\n = CR + LF --- Used as a new line character in Windows

Answer (score 0):

Don't put restrictions on it!
Create it as anything you like, and in your import logic, look for the three possibilities with Regex with a pattern similar to this: `(\\r|\\n|\\r\\n)`